# permute a string

Tags: java, string, algorithm, permutation

Given the String, print all its permutations. To do that, i came up with the following program.

```
public static char[] swap(char[] input, int i, int j) {
        char temp;
        temp = input[i];
        input[i] = input[j];
        input[j] = temp;

        return input;

    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param args
     */

    public static void permuteStrings(char[] inputString, int start, int finish ) {
        //Base case: When there is only single element, print the string
        if(start == finish) 
            System.out.println(inputString);
        else {
            //Recursive case: Swap first element with all the elements and permute on the 
                           // rest of string.
            for(int i = start; i <= finish; i++) {
                inputString = swap(inputString, start, i);
                permuteStrings(inputString, i + 1, finish);
                inputString = swap(inputString,start, i); //restoring the original string
            }
        }
    }
```

But, for the given input ABC, all it prints are

```
ABC
BAC
```

I cant seem to figure out what the problem is

Comment: I invoked it as permuteStrings(input,0,input.length -1). I figured the problem, i have added the answer for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the problem. The problem was in the function invocation:

`permuteStrings(inputString, i + 1, finish);`.

The correct way was:

```
permuteStrings(inputString, start + 1, finish);
```

Comment: So it was shadowing the i before i

Comment: The problem before was the condition "start == finish", would fail for the last recursive call

Answer (score 0):

Use recursion

```
public static void permutation(String str) 
{ 
permutation("", str); 
}
private static void permutation(String prefix, String str) {
int n = str.length();
if (n == 0) 
 System.out.println(prefix);
else 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
     permutation(prefix + str.charAt(i), str.substring(0, i) + str.substring(i+1, n));
}
}
```