# Combinations without repetitions

Tags: java, permutation, combinations

First off i am super sorry that i have no code for this. That is simply because i have yet to wrap my mind around the concept.
 I would like to be able to write a small java program that can take an ordered list of any number such that the list is 1 through number. Say for instance my number is 9. I would like this list to be `123456789` then i would like to create a program that creates EVERY possible combination of these 9 numbers. say for instance another combination would be `923456781`.
 Im going to be honest, i have no clue as how to even approach this.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutations

Comment: I think you can start my writing a method that when passed a number as argument returns the list of numbers.

Comment: @Quoi Homework tag is being removed from the SO. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated

Comment: Technically, this is called a *permutation* not a combination. So to start, let's back away from Java and use a smaller example, say `123`. List out all the permutations by hand. Then try it with `1234`. Can you find a systematic way to do this? Can you describe the steps in words?

Comment: +1 I am not aware of that. sorry ;)

Comment: @JakubZaverka: I think the link is about the number of combinations no the combinations itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd generate the first number as a string, 123456789, and then permute it.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12252782/509840 for permutations.

Comment: Believe this is what i was looking for. Ill have to mess around with it for a minute to check but im hopeful.

Comment: You are welcome! If you can wrap your head around recursion (having permuteString calling permuteString) then your question will open up a whole new area of computers.